# Beautiful Soup - better way to scrape specific elements of a table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping some publicly available retail data from the table at this URL: https://502data.com/retailers

My goal is to create a list in python for each column, e.g. a "Name_list" with all the entries in that column of the web table, a "County_list" and so on.

Here's my code for getting started with the scrape:

```
r = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
all_text = soup.get_text()
```

It seems to me that my all_text variable may not be necessary. It looks like there must be a slicker way to do this than I currently realize. For example:

```
all_text[7200:8000]
```

The above yields:

```
u', function($scope, $filter) {\n                    $scope.retailers = [{"licensenumber":"414876","name":"MAIN STREET MARIJUANA","city":"VANCOUVER","county":"CLARK","year":2017,"month":5,"sales":41170232.357500,"tax":14971101.020000,"recentSales":1374866.000000,"recentTax":508700.000000,"monthName":"May"}, ...
```

I can see that after $scope.retailers = I have all the information I want stored in what looks like an easy to parse way.

I'm just not familiar with Beautiful Soup enough to know the best commands for me to loop through this table, using either the soup or all_text variable, and pull out the data in each row of the web table.

Looking for a specific solution to this problem as well as any general BeautifulSoup advice for a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is not actually the HTML you want to parse, but rather JavaScript code, I would either use a JavaScript parser, like [`slimit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit), or use a *regular expression*:

```
import json
import re

import requests


url = "https://502data.com/retailers"
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36'})

pattern = re.compile(r"\$scope\.retailers = (\[.*?\]);")

match = pattern.search(response.text)
data = json.loads(match.group(1))
for item in data:
    print(item["name"])
```

The parenthesis here mean a ["capturing group"](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping), backslashes are used for escaping the characters.

Note that I'm applying the expression directly against the page source without using `BeautifulSoup` at all. We can though use it to locate this `script` element and then apply the expression on the `script` element's text.

Comment: Great, thanks! Can you explain what is being specified by 'headers' in the response variable?

Comment: @pavlov it is not really necessary to specify the custom user-agent header in this case, just my bad web-scraping habit :)

Comment: Ok, but what is that? You're specifying what computer and browser you're using for the scrape?

Comment: @pavlov it is basically for pretending to be a real browser.